# Odd Behavior On Export Using NodeJS Module

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Using the same code (see fiddle) and 3 different export URLs I get different export results. The issue is that the left side of the chart is clipping off the category titles but only if the export is JPG, PNG, or PDF - the SVG export is fine.
Current output for JPG, PNG, or PDF:
[image: clipped export]

This the expected output for those types and what SVG does export:
[image: expected output]

I have set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/pw09m98v/) - click on the image types at the top to see the issues while changing the `exporting.url` value.

This is the export code:

```
  window.chartExportLoc = function(chartid, exportType, graphHeader, graphFooter, marginSize) {
    var chartToExport = $('#' + chartid).highcharts(),
      sourceSpacingBottom = chartToExport.options.chart.spacingBottom;

    if (!marginSize) {
      marginSize = 15; //HighCharts default
    }

    chartToExport.exportChart({
      type: exportType,
      scale: 1,
      filename: chartid
    }, {
      title: {
        text: unescape(encodeURI(graphHeader)),
        margin: marginSize
      },
      subtitle: {
        y: 10,
        text: unescape(encodeURI(graphFooter))
      },
      chart: {
        shadow: false,
        width: 800,
        spacingBottom: sourceSpacingBottom - 20
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
```

We are running the highchart-export-server nodejs module and it is producing the clipped chart. If we change the `exporting.url` to use our existsing Java-based exporting application we get the correct/expected output. If we then change to use the export server hosted by highcharts (export.highcharts.com) it also produces the expected output.

I did file a [bug on github](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/issues/134) for this issue but no responses from highcharts and hoping someone here can assist. This is preventing us from moving forward with the nodejs implementation and finally sunsetting the Java-based export app.

Comment: A reply to your post on github has just appeared.

Comment: @KamilKulig, yes, I tried the upgraded export server (2.0.14) still no luck with the clipping.

Comment: Could you post your comment on github? It's better for the discussion if it happens in one place.

Comment: @KamilKulig, yes, already did.